# How can I pass data back to Main form in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#

I got this code where I put everything on Main form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "a")
        {
            GetSomeDataByA();
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "b")
        {
            GetSomeDataByB();
        }
        else 
        {
            GetSomeDataByC();
        }
    }

    private void GetSomeDataByA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("A error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("A");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("A is done");
    }
    private void GetSomeDataByB()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("B error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("B");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("B is done");
    }
    private void GetSomeDataByC()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("C error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("C");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("C is done");
    }
}
```

I would like to refactor this so I could have class A, class B, class C instead of 3 methods. Problem is I don't know how to handle data from class A so it shows MessageBox and fills listBox. Do I have to use delegates?

Comment: If possible create classes to return some kind of datasource and let the main form create instances of these classes and call the methods that return the datasource, It is the job of the form where the UI controls exist to manipulate them

Comment: You can create message boxes from any class as long as it is `using System.Windows.Forms`. As for the list boxes you can pass the listbox by reference and add items to it from another class. If you are using multiple threads you might run into issues with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass component which you want to fill with data in constructor of method and make it from static type like this code.

```cs
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "a")
        {
            ClassA.GetSomeDataByA(listBox1);
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "b")
        {
            ClassB.GetSomeDataByB(listBox1);
        }
        else 
        {
            ClassC.GetSomeDataByC(listBox1);
        }
    }

    // method inside ClassA. should be public to access it 
    public static void GetSomeDataByA(ListBox listBox1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("A error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("A");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("A is done");
    }

    // method inside ClassB. should be public to access it
    public static void GetSomeDataByB(ListBox listBox1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("B error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("B");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("B is done");
    }

    // method inside ClassC. should be public to access it
    public static void GetSomeDataByC(ListBox listBox1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("C error: ");
                return;
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("C");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("C is done");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using variables declared outside of the classes? I'm no good at C# but maybe if you store data in variables declared before the classes you may be able to switch between them. You can use something like `MessageBox.Show(variable1); listBoxname.Items.Add(variablestored1);`
But I think I gave that an error within itself or incorrect syntax. But I hope you get the jist of what I'm saying.

Comment: "Have you tried using variables declared outside of the classes?" C# does not support global variables. Best you can do is a static class, but not really the best practice.

Comment: Yes I meant something along those lines. I'm new to C# so I'm not entirely with it when it comes to this.